# Transact-SQL query subtotal column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subtotal

When my sql query returns the results it looks like this:

```
Driver    Amount
A         $120.00
A          -$5.00
A          $10.00
B          $90.00
```

But now I've been requested to add a column to the query results that will present the total for each driver. So it should now look like this:

```
Driver          Amount       Subtotal
A              $120.00        $125.00
A               -$5.00        $125.00
A               $10.00        $125.00
B               $90.00         $90.00
```

Possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use window functions.

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*,
       sum(amount) over (partition by driver) as subtotal
from cte;
```

You can probably incorporate this logic directly into the query that returns the first results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I can't provide you with the full query, but the following link may help accomplish what you need with GROUP BY and ROLLUP, if you're using MS SQL.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

one other way of doing this would be to use CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
With cteName as (
    Select DriverId,
    Sum(DriverAmount) As TotalDriverAmount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY DriverId
),
Select YourTable.DriverId, DriverAmount, cteName.TotalDriverAmount
FROM YourTable LEFT JOIN cteName ON(cteName.DriverId = YourTable.DriverId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.DRIVER, T.AMOUNT, S.TOT [SUBTOTAL] FROM YOURTABLE T JOIN 
(SELECT DRIVER, SUM(AMOUNT) TOT FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY DRIVER ) S 
ON T.DRIVER = S.DRIVER
```

This should work on just about any MS-SQL version.

Answer (score 0):

From
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1541134-3412-1.aspx

This is really easy thanks to some (Windowing) functionality born in 2005.

```
SELECT  OrderNo
        ,Something
        ,Amount
        ,SubTotal = SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo)    
FROM #TestTable   
ORDER BY OrderNo, Something
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a function that get driver Id, query driver data and return total, call that function in query

```
Select DriverId, Amount, func(driverId) as TotalAmount
FROM Table

    function func(ID){
   return(Select sum(amount) from table where driverid=ID);
    }
```

Comment: No need for function, when you can easily do it without it.